# "RegionCacheAdapter Unable to clear cache. Failed on region null. Last key null null"

Tags: java, spring, jvm, sap-commerce-cloud

During starting Hybris webapp i got a strange error:

INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/13 22:46:36.036 | ERROR [Thread-1] [RegionCacheAdapter] Unable to clear cache. Failed on region null. Last key null null

And app did not start afterwards. What can it be?

Comment: Can you share your Region Cache configuration ? And give us the full starting log ?

Answer (score 4):

Is this the first error you get when starting?
I have seen this error, but it was the consequence of previous ones, mainly related with spring. Check earlier console outputs, see if your system is complaining about some spring beans or something similar.