# I wanted to start my server as usual by running ./hybrisserver.show and an error is generated

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm working on a project with SAP COMMERCE on Hybris and the server failed to open due to this error

> ERROR [ShutdownHookThread] [RegionCacheAdapter] Unable to clear cache. Failed on region entityCacheRegion. Last key null null
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The entityCacheRegion Cache is not alive (STATUS_SHUTDOWN)

I tried reinstalling a new license and it didn't work.

Comment: Did you get any ehcache exception?

Comment: The error log is too small to make a conclusion.

Comment: The error in question is identical to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924403/regioncacheadapter-unable-to-clear-cache-failed-on-region-null-last-key-null - you should probably follow the advice given there and check the logs for exceptions that may have happened earlier on